# Is there another way of creating similar forms with different IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to duplicate forms but I want them to have different IDs. I will also be making use of the values entered in the forms so their IDs would have to be more or less similar. Thus, one form will have an id of "formA" and the next would be "formB". My workmate suggested appending the IDS with an int value. This is what I've done

```
var FormCounter = 1;

function addForms() {

    // When the element '#addForm' is clicked then the forms are appended to the formContainer div

    $("#addForm").click(function() {

         /* 
            Note: you can add as many forms as you want and each will have a different ID.
            Each ID will be unique as each ends with a different Integer.
        */

        var formTitle = "<p> Form " + formCounter + "</p>";

        // declare your form types here
        var formType = "<input type='textField' id='textField" + formCounter + "'</input>";

        // append to the formContainer div 
        $("#formContainer").append(formTitle);

        // create a form tag
        $("#formContainer").append("<form>");

        /* 

                INSERT FORMS HERE


        */

        $("#formContainer").append(formType);


        // close form tag
        $("#formContainer").append("</form>");

        // insert a horizontal line
        $("#formContainer").append("<hr>");

        ++formCounter;
    }); 
}
```

I currently make use of this code with one text field. Is there any other way of doing this? What I want to do after is get the values entered in the fields and then display them on a table.

Comment: Consider if an _id_ is really necessary here - if you're creating it in _JavaScript_ then you can get a reference to it quite easily at creation time. Please also note that appending open and close tags separately in _jQuery_ probably isn't behaving as you expect

Answer (score 0):

If you want to duplicate them you can use jquery to get the form, an then iterate trough each child making a new element on the same characteristics but finally changing the id is suggest using underscore uniq id. Hope it helps

Comment: At the end append the new form to the place you need

Comment: Also I would append all at once instead of doing it each time you create the el

Answer (score 0):

As in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/5bjua63p/2/) it briefly shows hwo to add more forms each with unique `id` - *as your workmate suggested* - also assign the counter value to the input and button of that corresponding form, then increase the counter

```js
var formCounter = 1;

$('#btn').on('click', function(){
 $('#formContainer').append('<p>form:' + formCounter + '<form id="f-'+formCounter+'"><input type="text" id="t-'+formCounter+'"><input type="submit" id="s-'+formCounter+'"></form></p>');
++formCounter;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Add a New Form</button>
<div id="formContainer"></div>
```

***UPDATE:*** As you asked for another way to do it, this code is with raw javascript, and instead of injecting the HTML code all in one append line like above, here we create each DOM element and set its ID and append its child to it, like this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/pbjkvb5g/1/)

```js
var i = 0, form, labelText, inputText, inputSubmit, btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    i++;
    form = document.createElement('form');
    form.id = 'form' + i;
    labelText = document.createElement('label');
    labelText.innerHTML = 'form ' + i + ': ';
    form.appendChild(labelText);
    inputText = document.createElement('input');
    inputText.setAttribute("type", "text");
    inputText.id = 'text' + i;
    form.appendChild(inputText);
    inputSubmit = document.createElement('input');
    inputSubmit.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    inputSubmit.id = 'sudmit' + i;
    form.appendChild(inputSubmit);
    document.getElementById("formContainer").appendChild(form);
});
```

```css
form {
    margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Add a New Form</button>
<div id="formContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Is there another way though?

Comment: We were told to write original code as much as possible. This looks more or less like my workmate's.

Comment: Ok, check the answer I've added another method using raw javascript hopefully it'll help

Comment: Ayt. Thank you very much!